# month difference between two dates in Scala

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have two dates in Scala of format 'yyyy-MM-dd' and they both are the last day of a month (2015-05-31) and I want to find the month difference between then. I have the following code but it is not straighforward to find the month difference.

```
 val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")         
 val diff = format.parse(date1).getTime - format.parse(date2).getTime

 val days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Java 8 or later, you can use the new Date and Time API in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

First, you create two `LocalDate` objects:

```
import java.time._
val s1 = LocalDate.parse("2012-05-31")
val s2 = LocalDate.parse(otherDate)
```

Then you have two options. First option, use the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) objects directly:

```
import java.time.temporal._
ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(s1, s2)   // the answer you are looking for
```

Or create a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) object, which is used to represent periods of time.

```
val p = Period.between(s1, s2)
p.getMonths() // returns the number of months between the two dates
```

The `Period` class has other methods, such as `getDays()`, that enables you to obtain more information about the period between the two dates.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Please keep in mind that a `Period` acts as a remainder to larger units. `getMonths` on something that is 15 months apart will return 3 and `getYears` will return 2. Because of this, I prefer the `ChronoUnit.Months.between` solution which would return 15.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple method there

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import spark.implicits._
val res=dataframe.withColumn("Month_Age",
functions.months_between(
  col("endDate"),
  col("startDate")
))
```

But before that you should have to parse your date string to date format if it is not in date format

You can check the schema by

```
dataframe.printschema()

root  |-- endDate: date (nullable = false)  

      |-- startDate_date: date (nullable = true)

      |-- Month_Age: Long (nullable = true)
```

You  can use

```
from_unixtime(col("Date")/1000).cast("date")
```

if the date is in epoch format.

Comment for any doubts.Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special method in `JodaTime`:

[monthsBetween](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Months.html#monthsBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant))

> Creates a Months representing the number of whole months between the two specified datetimes. This method corectly handles any daylight savings time changes that may occur during the interval.

Comment: how can I use it exactly in Scala?

Comment: FYI, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is in maintenance mode. The project advises migration to [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: @H.Z. JodaTime is a java library, so it can be used in Scala.